# Live mapping of JavaFX ObservableList or ReactFX LiveList

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, reactfx

```
/**
 * An observable analogue of {@code Stream.map}. The output list is updated
 * whenever the input list changes.
 */
public static <T, R> ListBinding<R> map(
    ObservableList<? extends T> list,
    Function<T, ? extends R> mapper
);
```

I wrote the above JavaFX utility method which creates a live mapping of an `ObservableList`, updating the mapping any time the source list changes. I later discovered [ReactFX](http://reactfx.org/) and its equivalent [`LiveList.map`](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4/org/reactfx/collection/LiveList.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
public interface LiveList {
    default <F> LiveList<F> map(Function<? super E,? extends F> f);
}
```

Not wanting to reinvent the wheel again, I am now looking for a map function which returns a list of observables and automatically watches those observables. Basically a [`flatMap`](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4/org/reactfx/value/Val.html#flatMap-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-java.util.function.Function-) for an entire list. For instance, if I had this:

```
<T, R> ListBinding<R> flatMap(
    ObservableList<? extends T> list,
    Function<T, ObservableValue<? extends R>> mapper
);
```

Then I could do this:

```
ObservableList<Button>  buttons;
ObservableList<Integer> widths = flatMap(buttons, Button::widthProperty);
```

This `widths` list would grow and shrink if buttons are added or removed, and would be updated if the buttons' widths change.

Does such a function exist in JavaFX or in ReactFX? Or anything similar?

Comment: See [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) (also by Tomas Mikula, who wrote ReactFX).

Comment: `flatMap` for observable lists is planned for ReactFX 2.0, though with a more general signature than yours, where each list item can be mapped to an observable _list_ of items (as opposed to a single observable value). You could combine it with [Val.asList()](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4/org/reactfx/value/Val.html#asList--) for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any existing implementation of `flatMap` for observable lists.

It is, however, planned for ReactFX 2.0, likely with this signature

```
public interface LiveList {
    default <F> LiveList<F> flatMap(Function<? super E,? extends ObservableList<F>> f);
}
```

which is more general than what you propose: it maps an element to a *list*, instead of just a single value.